# ASP.Net - How to hide a (print) button if any of the control values change

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In our current scheme we have an Crystal Report that can be shown once a record has been saved/changed.

What we want to do is add a 'print' button to the main data management form - allowing the user to print an existing report "as is". However, I want to disable/hide the print button if the user changes any of the 20+ fields (these controls are a mixture of check, text, & pull-down boxes).

Without having to add code change events for EVERY control, is there a way (assuming javascript) to capture a change to any one of the controls and then hide/disable the print button until the changes have been saved?

Edit:
Using the answer offered by @Bosco, the below code is a sample of our solution:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="TypeDDL" CssClass="dropDownList1 ChangeClass" runat="server"
<asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" class="descriptionText ChangeClass" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>


        $(".ChangeClass").on("change", ManagePrintButton);

    function ManagePrintButton() {
        //debugger;
        var btn = document.getElementById("btnPrintExport");
        btn.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Comment: Add a class to the controls and bind your event to the class.

Comment: Show an example of what you have done that did not work, do we even know the name or I'd of the print button.

Comment: @Bosco I'm still at the beginning steps of this; I have a button to open my CR form, but otherwise I've just been exploring possible options on how I might hide the button if/when fields are changed.

Comment: Thanks @Bosco - I edited my original question to add code snippets of our solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery wildcard selectors.

Give you inputs same class names and bind the change event to them this way

```
$(".theClass").on("change");
```

Another way is to use the id

Let's say that the IDs starts with a particular text/character or ends with a particular text/character

```
$("[id^=theText]")
//This gets all the elements that the id starts with theText

$("[id$=theText]")
 //This gets all the elements that the id ends with theText
```

also the JQuery documentation https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/